# When intercepting clicks, how to detect clicks on something nested inside an anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I'd like to prevent navigation away from a page, for test purpose (testing a navigation component)

I'm intercepting clicks at the page level, with a root element .onClick() (it's react but not sure it matters here.) I'm NOT controlling the page content.

In the page content, there are «A» links to other sites. I'm intercepting all clicks, but I'm only interested in the clicks navigating away, not clicks on UX elements like dropdowns.

Right now, after reading the doc for click events, I'm still unable to discriminate between clicks inside a navigation anchor and clicks on anything else: UI elements, dropdowns...

Existing answers suggest checking if target = «A», but since my «a» contain imbricated child «div»«div»... the click target ends up being a «div» and not a «a».

So, how can I check a click event to detect if it's a click on something inside an anchor, causing a navigation away from my page? (in order to preventDefault() it)

Or maybe there are other means to intercept navigation out of a page in a controlled way?

Comment: Can't you check if the target is an anchor *or has an anchor ancestor*, and if the latter is the case, consider the target to be the anchor ancestor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can walk up the element hierarchy to determine whether the event target is contained in an anchor:

```js
document.onclick = (e) => {
  let target = e.target;
  
  while(target) {
    if (target.tagName === 'A') {
      console.log('Clicked on anchor');
      break;
    }
    
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <span>Click <strong>here</strong></span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>
<br>
<span>Click here</span>
```

Comment: Good solution. I was hoping there would be some clever shortcut, though...

Comment: Just thought about using closest() http://devdocs.io/dom/element/closest which may simplify this

Comment: @Offirmo Yeah, definitely a good solution if you only have to support the latest browsers.